# Error during License server installation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager, saex

While trying to install license manager in Windows 10 PC I get this error:

`The ......\ARCGIS_LM.LOG couldn't be opened. The Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another program.`

I have end process of license manager from task manager but still the file cannot be accessed. Even deleting the file didnot work. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried ESRI support? For the amount you pay for ESRI software, you should expect first-class support from them.

Comment: @Spacedman not all ArcGIS users pay Maintenance on their software.  When they don't they do not have any support entitlement from Esri.  That does not mean that GIS SE should be used as a substitute support team.  We answer focused questions but "[**We are not a *formal* GIS Software Support Site**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)".

Comment: @PolyGeo Getting commercial software installed and running shouldn't require a separate maintenance contract. The supplier should be the first point of contact. Questioner has not said if they've done that, hence "does not show research effort" downvote and comment.

Comment: @Spacedman my recollection is that getting software installed and running comes under warranty but the software being talked about here may be 10+ years old, long out of warranty and being installed on a modern operating system. If it is a recent purchase (which I assume still comes with 12 months maintenance included making the warranty period moot) then I would certainly agree with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Esri Technical Article called [Error: The file ARCGIS_LM.LOG could not be opened](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010368) which says:

> This error occurs when the ArcGIS License Manager service is running
>   while the install or update is being made.

and provides instructions for how to try and resolve it.  These appear to have been written contemporary with ArcGIS 9.x but look like they are worth trying to apply to ArcGIS 10.x.